# is overriding's effect temporary or permanently?

Tags: c#, class, methods, overriding, equals

I wrote these lines of code in one of my programs in a solution to change the equality comparison between two instances of a class from their reference to their value:

```
public interface IEquatable<Clock>
{

}
public bool Equals(Clock theObj)
{
    if (theObj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (theObj.ToString() == this.ToString())
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
   if (obj == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    Clock clck = obj as Clock;
    if (clck == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return Equals(clck);
    }
}
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return Hours;
}`
```

and now when i try to compare two instances of a class using " Equals(T)" method in a different project in a different solution it compares their value not their reference.

does overriding a method in a project affect that method in other projects?

my complete code is:
    `using System;
    using System.Diagnostics.Contracts;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

```
public class Clock
{
    public int Minutes;
    public int Hours;
    public interface IEquatable<Clock>
    {

    }
    public bool Equals(Clock theObj)
    {
        if (theObj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (theObj.ToString() == this.ToString())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
       if (obj == null)
       {
           return false;
       }
       Clock clck = obj as Clock;
       if (clck == null)
       {
           return false;
       }
       else
       {
           return Equals(clck);
       }
   }
   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
       return Hours;
   }
   public override string ToString()
   {
       if (Hours < 10)
       {
           if (Minutes < 10)
           {
               return "0" + Hours + ":0" + Minutes;
           }
           else
           {
               return "0" + Hours + ":" + Minutes;
           }
       }
       else
       {
           if (Minutes < 10)
           {
               return Hours + ":0" + Minutes;
           }
           else
           {
               return Hours + ":" + Minutes;
           }
       }
   }
   public Clock(int hours, int minutes)
   {
       while (minutes > 59 || minutes < 0)
       {
           if (minutes > 59)
           {
               minutes -= 60;
               hours++;
           }
           if (minutes < 0)
           {
               minutes += 60;
               hours--;
           }
       }

       while (hours > 23 || hours < 0)
       {
           if (hours > 23)
           {
               hours -= 24;
           }

           if (hours < 0)
           {
               hours += 24;
           }
       }
       Hours = hours;
       Minutes = minutes;
   }

   public Clock Add(int minutesToAdd)
   { 
       var res = new Clock(Hours , Minutes + minutesToAdd);
       return res;
   }

   public Clock Subtract(int minutesToSubtract)
   {
       var res = new Clock(Hours , Minutes - minutesToSubtract);
       return res;
   }}
```

thank you for your time!

Comment: Imagine it rephrased as this: “If I write a class/method in library A, is that class/method usable in library B?” - Equals is just a method defined (or overridden) in some type, and thus the same rules apply.

Comment: Also, the interface definition here, presented at the top of the code example, is.. incorrect. Re-verify how to implement interfaces, and make sure to post compiling code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic of your `Equals` method is wrong! for classes without `ToString` method override, The output is something like this `StackOverflowCodes.Clock`, Which results in all objects being equal!
Please take a look at following code for more ideas:

```
public class Clock : IEquatable<Clock>
{
    public int Hours { get; set; }
    public int Minutes { get; set; }
    public int Seconds { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(Clock c)
    {
        if (c == null)
            return false;
        // Here is a somewhat correct logic for equality (sort of ...)
        //return c.Hours == Hours && c.Minutes == Minutes;
        return c.ToString() == this.ToString();
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() => Hours * 3600 + Minutes * 60 + Seconds;
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var clock = obj as Clock;

        if (clock != null)
            return Equals(clock);
        return false;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Clock c2 = new Clock { Hours = 12, Minutes = 01, Seconds = 59 };
        var c1 = new Clock { Hours = 12 };

        Console.WriteLine(c1.Equals(c2));
        Console.WriteLine(Equals(c1, c2));
        Console.WriteLine(c1 == c2);

        Console.WriteLine(c1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(c2.ToString());
    }
```

And for your question, If you are referencing the project/solution which have your defined `Clock` type, Then you are using that custom logic you defined, Otherwise they should not have anything in common.